# Documentation of ERP customizations

Tags: documentation, enterprise, documentation-generation, erp

I would like to know, if you have a **good guidline or if there are tools for documentating the customization in an ERP system**. In my case, I am working on Infor SyteLine ERP 8, but the question will probably arise for every ERP.

The difficulty for documentation of ERP customization is, that the intelligence and data are far spread:

- SyteLine ERP:

  - Form scripts (VB.NET, C#)
  - Form events
  - Event handler for global events
  - Background tasks
- Database SQL Server:

  - Stored Procedures
  - Functions
  - User defined data types
- Microsoft Report Builder:

  - Report templates

As an example: Creating a report involves form scripting, form events, background task, stored procedures and then the report as such.

Do you have experience or an idea how to document everything in one place? I also want sometimes to comment form events, but that is in SyteLine not even directly possible. Or ist there a way how to combine the documentations from the different places? For example, do we document each customized or added database functionality. But even there, it is difficult to document an SQL Server Agent task.

Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, first of all, a complete documentation of your standard version is a must.

As the project goes on, we may have some customizations, we documented it as "Change Log".

Yes, it is hard to maintain the documentation as a single dimension, for example 
-when you changed/add database field, you need 'DB change log'; 
-when you changed/form events, you need to take note on maybe 'USE CASE' diagram.
-when you hide some information in report, you need to note it somewhere else.
-etc.

As an ERP developer myself, I always get a mixed-up documentations, some of which seems to be un-related but actually they are. Then now I managed to get the documentation by abundant of list but maintain the dimension, e.g:

-One Excel for List of:
    -

- Settings     -Module/SubModule   -Form of Module/SubModule   -Feature in
  General  -User & UserGroup & License     -Data Category  -Authorization
  of User towards Module/SubModule     -Authorization of User towards Data
  Category     -Approval Flow  -Report     -Table & Field Used for Report
  -Table & Field Used for Form

-One Excel for List of Process Flow for each module in each sheet.

I think it must cover :

- for other people to understand easily how it works,
- for other people to easily find the original feature,
- what other types of 'this data' is available,
- what other category of 'this feature' related to this module is
  available and their status and timeline,
- what effect this form changes do with other users,
- etc.

It is tons of lists that need to be maintain as simple as possible.

How did you do your documentation currently?

Comment: We have a wordfile which contains the implementation changes for the ERP system as such. In addition, we maintain a company Wiki and have one page with high-level user documentation (e.g. which button does what? A column in a report displays which information?).
Furthermore, we started to use SVN for our MSSQL DB, thence table changes, stored procedure changes, ... are tracked. However, source control comments are difficult to get a good overview. It is more useful for specific change investigations.

Comment: During change request from clients, we gather Business Requirements, break down to Functional Requirements, then break down again to Technical Requirements, and we have a set of Business Rules (Validation).  We don't manage company wikis, but we're working with tons of list, for example: if X form open, what list of button available, how GUI responds, how to get data, etc. I believe in a level of managing company wikis, you have more complex lists.